# How to sit Divs responsively under elements defined by width

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyent531/)

I am looking to have one element (`main`) sit just below the carrousel (`mySlider`) without any margin or spaces. I want this to work on all devices at different scales.

The problem is `myslider` (which is using '[simpleslider](https://github.com/ruyadorno/simple-slider)') seems to have to be sized by width to work reactively and thus does not cascade correctly with the Div below it. So far, I have been using the `@media` syntax to define the margin so the two elements are positioned how I want them, however doing this for every screen-size/device is taking forever and never 100% accurate.

Failing a simple fix for this, I would happily switch to another carrousel at this point as this has been an issue for a while.

This is my first time making a site fully reactive so I'm sorry if this is a silly question!

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also mention that the images in the carousel cannot stretch/warp, so must remain in their initial aspect ratio.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyent531/) again for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a plugin which is called swiper

Here is the fiddle that I create for you

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/justicechan/3sm2zh95/11/)

Here is the api
[swiper spi](https://swiperjs.com/api/)

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/3600x2000"></div>
   <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/3600x2000"></div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/3600x2000"></div>
     <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/3600x2000"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/3600x2000"></div>
</div>
<!-- Add Pagination -->
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<!-- Add Arrows -->
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div><!--main-->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

js

```
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

css

```
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;

}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide  img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.main {
background-color: cyan;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately this seems to stretch the images in the carousel. I will edit the original post to mention that the images cannot be stretched. Additionally this seems to only work on smaller screen sizes and on a desktop the `main` Div positions itself over the carousel.